# Swift access fields in nested dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nested

I've got to deal with a Dictionary like this, or more nested.
How can I access fields like "twotwo" ? Or is there any better possibility to model such structure?

```
let nestedDict = [
    "fieldOne": "name",
    "fieldTwo": "name",
    "fieldThree":
        [
            [
            "twoOne": "some text",
            "twoTwo": true,
            "twoThree": 1e-40
            ],
            [
            "twoOne": "some text",
            "twoTwo": true,
            "twoThree": 1e-40
            ]
        ]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `nestedDict["fieldThree"]["twoTwo"]`?

Comment: There are some arrays in between an nestedDict["fieldThree"][0][0]["twoTwo"] will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nestedDict` is a `Dictionary`, you get `fieldThree` with

```
let fieldThree = nestedDict["fieldThree"] as! [[String:Any]] // [[String:AnyObject]] in Swift 2 and lower.
```

`fieldThree` is an `Array`of `[String:AnyObject]` dictionaries, you get the value of `twoTwo` of the first array item with

```
let twoTwo = fieldThree[0]["twoTwo"] as! Bool
```

You can even retrieve all values of key `twoTwo` in the array

```
let allTwoTwo = fieldThree.map { $0["twoTwo"] as! Bool }
```